# Using a Variable to Determine the Table to SELECT From

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

this is new error I get:

```
IF object_id('Osvezi') IS NULL

EXEC sp_executesql N' 
CREATE PROCEDURE Osvezi
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tablica nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
   IF @tablica = 'Uporabniki' THEN SELECT * FROM Uporabniki;

   IF @tablica = 'Dokumenti' THEN SELECT * from Dokumenti;
END'
GO
```

Comment: You can't switch data sources that way.

Comment: Yea I tried without declaring new variable but I get same error

Comment: You should give up on this entire idea. `SELECT *` by itself is a bad idea. Combining it with dynamically choosing the table is a worse idea. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I am trying to do is next. I am writing application in c# that call's certain procedure in Sql server database. As parameter this procedure is receiving variable which has name of table in it. And with that parameter I want to refresh only certain table. Because I have like 10 procedures and I don't want to refresh all table's I want only ones that is changed depending on sended parameter... I hope you understand. Thank's in advance

Comment: It's too late at night for me to get the syntax right, but use `IF @tableName = 'Table1' THEN SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1;` IF @tableName = 'Table2' THEN SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Tabel2;`

Comment: I have edited my newest error I get when I used your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use double `''` in the string to get one `'` and you need to remove `then`.

```
IF object_id('Osvezi') IS NULL
EXEC sp_executesql N' 
CREATE PROCEDURE Osvezi
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tablica nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
   IF @tablica = ''Uporabniki'' SELECT * FROM Uporabniki;

   IF @tablica = ''Dokumenti'' SELECT * from Dokumenti;
END'
GO
```

Comment: This only would work if there were only that number of possible tables it would need change each time a table is added or deleted

Comment: @jclozano - This question has changed since you provided your answer. My answer fixes the syntax that the OP got wrong. Why the down vote?

Comment: Because although you do solve the question in a nice way; it requires maintenance each time the structure of the DB changes or if he requires to add a table to the ifs, that's mostly why I suggested the EAV Model so that he doesn't have to change his procedure each time a table is added or removed

Comment: Although it would be easier if @Denonth told us if it will be possible to add or remove tables to his SP

Comment: @jclozano So you down vote this answer because OP has a bad design going. Fair enough. If I understood from the question why this is needed I might have provided a different answer but since there are no hints in there at all I will just settle for fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: I didn't downvoted because of his bad design, i downvoted because you answered without considering that it would be better to point him of such bad design.

Comment: "Give a Man a fish and he will eat for a day; teach him how to get fish for himself and he will eat his whole life"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this but it is NOT RECOMMENDED

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Osvezi
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tablica nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM' + @tablica);
END
```

Also it would depend on which DBMS you are using; SQL SERVER? MYSQL? POSTGRESQL?

**Edit:**

If you need this kind of flexibility, try the [Entity-Attribute-Value Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: Then my answer should work; but as I state on my answer you should use instead the EAV Model